# How do I execute an implemented method in Rust?

Tags: rust

I can't execute method which name is `two_sum` implemented in a Solution impl.
I want to know how to execute `two_sum` method from `main`.

My source code is here.

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn two_sum(num: i32) -> i32 {
        num + 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let result = Solution::two_sum(1);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Error message

```
failed to resolve: use of undeclared type Solution
use of undeclared type Solution
```

Comment: It appears you haven't declared `Solution` as a `struct` or `enum`. Why are you `impl`ing that function on a non-existing type? Are you attempting to namespace it? Maybe you should just use a module instead?

Comment: @PitaJ looks like just the regular shitty leetcode template plus a `main` to me.

Answer (score 4):

You need define what `Solution` is and later implement two_sum. One way is you can define `Solution` as an empty struct.

```
struct Solution;

impl Solution {
    pub fn two_sum(num: i32) -> i32 {
        num + 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let result = Solution::two_sum(1);
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, firstly, your `two_sum` is an associated function, not a method. Secondly, it’s associated with *nothing* - you didn’t declare a type named `Solution` (you needed to write `struct Solution;` at least). Thirdly, you don’t need to `Debug` an `i32`, so we’ll replace `{:?}` with `{}`.

```rust
struct Solution;

impl Solution {
    pub fn two_sum(num: i32) -> i32 {
        num + 1
    }
}

fn main() {
    let result = Solution::two_sum(1);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Fourthly, creating a type just to write a function is a really bad practice.

So what are we gonna do?

```rust
fn two_sum(num: i32) -> i32 {
    num + 1
}

fn main() {
    let result = two_sum(1);
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

That’s it! I don’t know why did you call it `two_sum` tho.